# Powershell AD password reset on on multi domain controllers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have 4 or 5 DC in different locations and I would like to write a Powershell script that would reset the password to a user account on all DC at one time so they do not have to wait for replication or I don't have to go to the nearest DC to reset it for them.

Answer (score 0):

The [Set-ADAccountPassword](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617261.aspx) command has a `Server` parameter, where you can tell it which domain controller to use.

You can use one of these methods to get a list of DCs in your domain: http://use-powershell.blogspot.ca/2013/04/find-all-domain-controllers-in-domain.html

Loop through the list of DCs and call `Set-ADAccountPassword` with each one.